# Is it acceptable to accept your own answer

Tags: discussion

...when you posted the answer with the question and checked the "Answer your own question – share your knowledge, Q&A-style" box?

Should you wait a period of time to give the community a chance to vet and perhaps provide a better answer?

I have gotten a nice ego (and reputation) boost from the reception [this post of mine](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/61364/i-have-just-returned-to-my-raspberry-pi-after-a-year-and-cant-remember-my-login/61365?noredirect=1#comment95796_61365) has received but didn't want breech protocol by accepting the answer that I had posted with the question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is acceptable and accepted to accept your own answer.

As you have figured out yourself doing so *might* discourage others from providing additional helpful answers. So waiting a day or two seems to be a good idea. Other than that grace period there is no strict protocol to follow (or breech) here. It really is what you would consider appropriate. Just give it a few days and accept if no other stellar answer arrives. (I am of course assuming that the answer addresses and solves the question posted...)